# Selecting timeline item 'content' vis.js

Tags: javascript, timeline, vis.js

Is there a way to select a timeline items 'content'?

```
timeline.on('select', function (properties) {
  alert('selected items: ' + properties.items);
});
```

This only selects the item id. Can this be done within vis.js or do I need to use something else like jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

i'm just using jquery to match the id against each item.

Comment: And how? Can't find any informations...

Answer (score 0):

## Get HTML Content

properties.event.firstTarget.innerHTML

## Get Text Content

properties.event.firstTarget.innerText